# Find the repeating number in an unsorted array

Tags: repeat

1000 or 10000 numbers in range (0-10^9) are given. There is just one number that repeats twice. Find that number in O(n) time and O(1) space complexity.

Comment: Interesting question, but have you attempted an answer yet yourself?

Comment: You didn't forget to mention that the input is sorted by accident, did you?

Comment: The array is unsorted

Comment: Yes I did. But I couldnt come up with a way. So I posted it here.